# Force Delete on a UNIQUE rows SQLite FMDB iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have an app which uses SQLite, i have some problems deleting a row because one of its value is unique. 
I get the error :

```
Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (19: column myField is not unique) 
DB Query: DELETE FROM  "****" WHERE "myField" = '72645DA9-E95F-452A-94B8-C93A20D9A41C'
```

Is there a way to force the delete of this unique row ? Or can simply disable the unique constraint when i need to delete.

Of course this behavior should not appear, but it does so please do not tell to re-create my database :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: This error cannot happen during a DELETE operation (unless you have a trigger that does an INSERT/UPDATE elsewhere).

Comment: Your right it is my trigger which cause this ! thanks !